# why WPF Window.Visibility binding must have Mode=TwoWay for property's get to be called?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

ViewModel:

```
    public FloatingToolbarWindowViewModel(GuiItems guiItems)
    {

        GuiItemsInstance = guiItems;
        GuiItemsInstance.Host = Host;
        GuiItemsInstance.RefreshVisibility = RefreshVisibility;
    }

    private Visibility _windowVisibility;
    public Visibility WindowVisibility
    {
        get { return _windowVisibility; }
        set
        {
            //raises PropertyChanged-event
            SetValue(ref _windowVisibility, value);
        }
    }
    // this check if any of the toolbars should be in a window and then sets visibility
    public void RefreshVisibility(int RoleId)
    {
        if (GuiItemsInstance.ToolbarItems.Any(i => i.ToolbarLocation == ToolbarLocation.Float && i.RoleId == RoleId))
            WindowVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            WindowVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

XAML:

```
 Visibility="{Binding WindowVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

This means it can never work because in the end the ShowWindow updates the property to Visible even though the initialization would have "decided" it should be Hidden.

So what I do is a hack in code behind file:

```
public partial class FloatingToolbarWindow : Window
{
    public FloatingToolbarWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentRendered += FloatingToolbarWindow_ContentRendered;
    }

    private void FloatingToolbarWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ((FloatingToolbarWindowViewModel)DataContext).RefreshWindowVisibility();
    }
```

ViewModel extra Hack-method:

```
    public void RefreshVisibility()
    {
        RefreshVisibility(GuiItemsInstance.ActiveRoleId);
    }
```

Is there a way to do this without this terrible hack. Moreover shouldn't this work with Mode=OneWay binding in the 1st place?

Comment: What is `SetValue(ref _windowVisibility`? Why not `SetValue(*.VisibilityProperty`?

Comment: sorry, it is this abstract class ViewModel method i use.. it raises PropertyChanged-event. this causes get to be called but only when TwoWay--binding.

Comment: What is "ShowWindow"? Do you mean Window.Show?

Comment: again sorry, it's a method  that is used to open the window. It does call Window.Show which is not good in my TwoWay-binding. My example is very bad because of the toolkit  I use, I thought TwoWay is normal case for Window.Visibility binding and I was asking why it has to be. My bad. My question is edited to describe how i hacked it to work, if that exxplains what is really wrong here.

Comment: Are you by any chance setting the window visibility directly in code behind (perhaps in your `ShowWindow` method)? And if so, could you share that part of the code?

Comment: i do not have the code, but it calls both Show and Hide because TwoWay-binding updates the property 2 times. maybe i shouldn't have posted this in the 1st place because there is so much happening that's in toolkit/framework i use. thanks for effort, still wondering why oneway binding results get-called zero times.

Comment: My guess would be that somewhere in that code there's a call to `SetValue` on the window's `Visibility` property (which is the case with the setter). This method behaves differently based on the binding mode - for modes supporting target-to-source (two-way, one-way-to-source) it updates the source, while for modes supporting only source-to-target (one-way, one-time) it replaces the binding with just the local value (the binding no longer works). That would explain the fact that it works for two-way binding and not for one-way.

Comment: thanks. this makes sense.

Comment: So no one really knows the answer to this question?
Pitty^^

Answer (score 0):

I'd make WindowVisibility a readonly property:

```
public Visibility WindowVisibility
{
        get 
        { 
         if (GuiItemsInstance.ToolbarItems.Any(i => i.ToolbarLocation == ToolbarLocation.Float && i.RoleId == RoleId))
        return Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

bind the visibility OneWay:

```
Visibility="{Binding WindowVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"
```

and then whenever you have to "update" the visibility just raise the property changed... I don't know what you are using, could either

```
OnPropertyChanged("WindowVisibility");
```

or

```
OnPropertyChanged(() => WindowVisibility);
```

Comment: thanks! any explanation why this would work if the problem is that get is never called unless the binding is TwoWay?

Comment: sorry, get not called when raising event.